# Welcome Screen, Redirecting to main page

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I want to make a welcome screen that redirects to the main page after say 5 seconds. I tried this but it doesnt work.

```
<script>
function myFunc()
{
setTimeout('Decrement()',5000);
}
function Decrement()
{
location="index.html";
}
</script>


</head>

<body onload="myFunc()">
```

This is in the welcome page. How do i get it to work?

Comment: Some errors in console?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use JavaScript instead of just a meta refresh?

Comment: i didnt know about meta refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo on function declaration:

change it to:

```
function myFunc()
{
setTimeout('Decrement()',5000);
}
```

also verify that `index.html` exists at the same folder as your html page

Comment: ya i changed that but meta refresh is simpler thanks @Dor Cohen

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=index.html">
```

This is a much simpler way.

Thanks @Syfaro